# Get directory name from Path object without a slash at the end

Tags: java, java.nio.file

When I have a `Path` object (in my case, it's relativized path coming from `Files.walkFileTree`), `path.getFileName().toString()` may give me a name with a slash at the end. Is there some simple builtin method to guarantee it's either always or never there?

Comment: `String filePath = path.getFileName().toString().trim(); if (filePath.endsWith("/")) { filePath = filePath.substring(0, (filePath.length() - 1)); }`

Comment: Is this guaranteed to also work on windows which uses `\\` as separator? Javadoc is very unhelpful in explaining what is a valid value it can return an what isn't.

Comment: This I would think should do it: `String filePath = path.getFileName().toString().trim(); if (filePath.endsWith(File.separator) || filePath.endsWith("/")) { filePath = filePath.substring(0, (filePath.length() - 1)); }`
       }